# how to split the code so that it runs on two computers

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I 'd like to split the code into two parts so that part of it runs on my PC and another part run on the Intel board (computer of the robot) at the same time and connects between them using WiFi.
my issue: I am running the code for vision-based tracking and map using lidar data. As a result, the frame per second is low and the robot's movement is not smooth. So, I'd like to run the code vision-based tracking on my PC and another part based on lidar data on the computer of the robot.

if it is possible. Please help me or any suggestions and what are its disadvantages?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337814/how-to-split-the-code-so-that-it-runs-on-two-computers/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible, the pc on your robot will master and your pc will be slave. You can follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/ut-ims-robotics/tutorials/wiki/Running-ROS-over-multiple-computers) to accomplish that. Once the communication is established you can run your lidar node on intel board and camera node on your own pc. But you have to keep bandwidth limitations in your mind.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-18**:
Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
Happy to help :)

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-19**:
I understood that I need to use the same topic and it is a Publisher on master and Subscriber in slave, it is easy with `from std_msgs.msg import String`. how to do it if I'd like to send numbers as `float`?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
Slave is only physically apart from master, otherwise have access to all the topics/nodes/services and master has same for slave. Just think of it as you are using the same machine, nothing is different except your access to larger messages like image and pointcloud might be slower. Can you explain last part of your question, I didn't quite get what you are trying to do.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-19**:
I am changing in these codes in order to understand it ,  (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) it works with me because of the topic works as a Publisher and as a Subscriber at the same time but if I need to use the topic of velocity. how to implement it? because it is always working as a Publisher, it is not working with me. another thing, this ex. hello world works with `String` as `type (string data)`. if I need to use `type (float data)` which one should I use instead of `String`?

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-19**:
I got a `float`  (http://wiki.ros.org/msg)  but the topic of velocity still not clear with me how to implement it?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
I would suggest you go over ROS beginner [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and get a grasp of how ROS ecosystem works. From this you will get at least basic understanding of what you can do and how to do it and you will be better able to navigate your way instead of asking every small detail. To answer your question ROS distro comes with a lot of messages and you can also make your own messages if needed. Float is part of `std_msgs/Float32` and so is string.
You can also use command line to publish a message like
`rostopic pub /topic_name message_type message`. Where you can tab autocomplete message_type and message.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
For velocity you can use [Twist](https://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) or any variant of it like TwistStamped. You can use `rosmsg show geometry_msgs/Twist` to see what message contains. Like everything ROS related tab autocomplete works here as well and you can see all variants of Twist or all the messages avaiable to you.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-19**:
thank you so much @Choco93

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-11-19**:
Sorry, I have a good background with ROS. I don't mean these commands but I mean how to run the codes on both computers using the topic of velocity like this example (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)). they used `chatter` topic